# cannot find symbol MainFragment

Tags: android-studio

hello when i try rebuild app i get 2 errors
1- cannot find symbol
MainFragment fragment= (MainFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);

2-error: cannot find symbol
ResultFragment res= (ResultFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment3);

mainactivity file

```
package com.rqeeqa.wheightcalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

mainfragments

```
package com.rqeeqa.wheightcalculator.fragment;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
import com.rqeeqa.wheightcalculator.R;
import com.rqeeqa.wheightcalculator.Result;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    Button apps,share,mag,art,calc;
    EditText length,wheight,year,cycle;
    String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault());
    TextView textView5,textView6,textView7,textView8;
    int count=0;
    InterstitialAd interstitial;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        String languageToLoad  = "ar"; // your language
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getActivity().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());



        AdView mAdView =  view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        // AdView mAdView2 = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView2);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();


       /*AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
                .addTestDevice("80610B9039A1685F0FFB3A685B24E849")  // My Galaxy Nexus test phone
                .build();*/
        mAdView.loadAd(request);

        //mAdView2.loadAd(adRequest);



        textView6=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        textView5=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        textView8=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView8);

        apps=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.apps);
        share=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.share);
        mag=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.mag);

        calc=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.calc);
        wheight=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.day);

        length=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.cycle);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/DIN-NEXT_-ARABIC-REGULAR.otf");

        textView6.setTypeface(font);
        textView5.setTypeface(font);
        textView8.setTypeface(font);
        mag.setTypeface(font);
        calc.setTypeface(font);
//        art.setTypeface(font);
        apps.setTypeface(font);
        share.setTypeface(font);

        calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                calculate();
            }
        });






        apps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent8=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent8.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Doctor%20Soft%20App"));
                startActivity(intent8);

            }
        });
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "حاسبة الوزن");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rqeeqa.wheightcalculator");
                startActivity(shareIntent);



            }
        });
        mag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent8=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent8.setData(Uri.parse("https://rqeeqa.com/"));
                startActivity(intent8);
            }
        });



        return view;
    }
    public void calculate(){
        if(wheight.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"لم تقم بادخال الوزن",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
         else if(length.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"لم تقم بادخال الطول",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else{

            double l= Double.parseDouble(length.getText().toString());

            double wight= Double.parseDouble(wheight.getText().toString());
            l=l/100;
            l=l*l;
            double w=wight/l;
            double p=(24*l);
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),Result.class);

            intent.putExtra("weight",w);
            intent.putExtra("perfect",p);
            MainFragment fragment= (MainFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
            ResultFragment res= (ResultFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment3);

            if (res != null && res.isVisible()) {
                res.show(intent);
            }
            else {
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    }


}
```

i try diffrent solutions from internet but not fix